# Java Swing Layouts and Menus

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Ok so I am having trouble using the grid layout to arrange the window in this format, I want to arrange each label and its text field to an individual line and then have a centered button at the bottom.

```
  public class Main extends JFrame {

   //below is how i want to format the frame
        /*label textfield
          label textfield   
          label textfield   
              button*/

         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField nameText = new JTextField(15);
        JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel("Address");
        JTextField addressText = new JTextField(15);

        public Main(){
            setTitle("JSWING");
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
            setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(450,250);

         //setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panel.add(nameLabel);
            panel.add(nameText);
            panel.add(addressLabel);
            panel.add(addressText);


            add(panel);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Main mainFrame = new Main();
            //mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Draw in paint what do you need. You may as well use `GridLayout` to what you stated in OP.

Comment: I added it as a comment in the code, how i want it to look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//setVisible(true); // don't do this until all components are added to the frame.
...
add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
buttonPanel.add( button );
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
setVisible(true);
```

The default layout manager for a frame is a BorderLayout. So you can add multiple panels to the frame. One panel containing your labels/text fields and the other containing your button.